# Detect/remove duplicate values in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to determine if a list has repeated values. How can I do this?

I have 3 groups of lists:

```
Link_a =     ['a','b','c']    
Bookmark_a = ['1','2','3']    
Link_b =     ['b','c']    
Bookmark_b = ['4','5']    
Link_c =     ['a']    
Bookmark_c = ['6']
```

I want to reduce this to a single set of links, and a single set of bookmarks, like this result:

```
Answer_link_all =     ['a','b','c']    
Answer_bookmark_all = ['7', '6', '8']
```

I first tried `link_a + link_b`, but I found the values will repeat:

```
link_a + link_b   # result: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
```

I think what I want to do is something like this pseudocode:

```
if name is repeat pass    
   or add tag name
```

But there are still bookmarks to calculate also, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: why Answer_bookmark_all = ['7', '6', '8']?

Comment: What the heck, dude? Maybe Google Translate could help?

Comment: I kinda understand this. So you want to add to a list only if the variable is not present in the previous list and If it is already there, then add the value to the bookmarks?

Comment: @BAE: Looks like the OP is computing totals for each of `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. E.g., the Link_a / Bookmark_a pair maps 'a' to 1, and the Link_c / Bookmark_c pair maps 'a' to 6; the total for 'a' is therefore 7. Similarly for 'b' and 'c'.

Comment: @BhargavRao YES!  ,sorry my english is bad

Comment: @MarkDickinson thank your explan

Comment: Do you have the option to use Python 3 for this? It's a perfect use case for [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: @DanLowe really!? ,well my firind already tell me for sets is better but  i have many don't know about python 3

Comment: I'll add an answer with some information about sets...

Comment: @DanLowe you are great!!

Comment: @DanLowe really really thank your edit ,i think i should learn more english 囧 ,anyway thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will be better off using a dictionary instead of having disconnected lists for the labels and their values. Also, consider using actual integers as the values, not strings.

Here's a suggestion:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c.update(dict((x,int(y)) for x,y in zip(Link_a, Bookmark_a)))
>>> c.update(dict((x,int(y)) for x,y in zip(Link_b, Bookmark_b)))
>>> c.update(dict((x,int(y)) for x,y in zip(Link_c, Bookmark_c)))
>>> c
Counter({'c': 8, 'a': 7, 'b': 6})
```

Whenever you get new data, update your Counter accordingly. Access the Counter like this:

```
>>> c['a']
7
>>> c['b']
6
>>> c['c']
8
```

Comment: @busystudent no problem, please try to ask a more precise question next time, you had me really confused for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You could `zip` the different pairs of lists,

```
Link_a =     ['a','b','c']    
Bookmark_a = ['1','2','3']    
Link_b =       ['b','c']    
Bookmark_b =  ['4','5']    
Link_c =     ['a']    
Bookmark_c = ['6']

zps = [
    zip(Link_a, Bookmark_a),
    zip(Link_b, Bookmark_b),
    zip(Link_c, Bookmark_c),
]

d = dict()
for z in zps:
    for k,v in z:
        v = int(v) # Converting v to a number 
        if k not in d: d[k] = v; continue
        d[k] += v

Answer_link_all = list(d.keys())
Bookmark_link_all = list(d.values())
```

Comment: wow i don't know python have zip , i think i should learn, and thank your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this:

```
Link_a =     ['a','b','c']    
Bookmark_a = ['1','2','3']    
Link_b =       ['b','c']    
Bookmark_b =  ['4','5']    
Link_c =     ['a']    
Bookmark_c = ['6']


def to_dict(a,b):
    return {k: int(v) for k, v in zip(a,b)}


def merge_dicts(x,y):
    return { k:x.get(k, 0) + y.get(k, 0) for k in set(x) | set(y) }


res = merge_dicts(to_dict(Link_a, Bookmark_a), to_dict(Link_b, Bookmark_b))
res = merge_dicts(res, to_dict(Link_c, Bookmark_c))

print res
```

Result: `{'a': 7, 'c': 8, 'b': 6}`

Comment: thank you answer !! i really don't know def can write this code.

Comment: My pleasure. You can upvote it if it was helpful (arrow up on the left). Do you understand the code or do you need some explanation ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for [sets](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which were introduced in Python 3.x, but have been backported to Python 2.7.

A list, which is you are using currently, is an ordered, sequential series of values. As you have seen, the values can repeat and you have to do extra work to summarize a list to only its unique values.

Like a list, a set is a collection of values. However, they are not ordered, and they are not sequential. Also, in a set, a value cannot repeat. If you add a value to a set, and it is already a member of the set, you do not get a duplicated value; it still only appears in the set one time.

Sets are modeled on sets in mathematics.

(The below examples assume Python 2.7 - the syntax is a little different in Python 3.)

You can create a set using literal notation:

```
Link_a = set(['a','b','c'])
```

One caveat - if you pass a string instead, it will split the string into its component letters. That's because in Python, strings are also iterable.

```
Link_a = set('abc')     # now: set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

You can get around that by passing a single-element tuple or list instead.

```
Link_a = set(('abc',))  # now: set(['abc'])
Link_a = set(['abc'])   # now: set(['abc'])
```

You can also create an empty set, and add to it after the fact.

```
Link_a = set()                    # now: set([])
Link_a.update(['a', 'b', 'c'])    # now: set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
Link_a.update('d')                # now: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
Link_a.update('a')                # now: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
```

As you can see, the last `update` we did (`a`), did not change the set. `a` was already a set member, so nothing happened when we tried to add it again.

Note: as you can see from the examples, sets are *not ordered*. If you are relying on the values being in a certain order, sets may not work for you (or, you may need to sort them in some way when using them).

As with lists, you can use comprehensions, you can test for membership with `in`...

```
'd' in Link_a    # True
'z' in Link_a    # False
```

You can also use mathematical operations on sets.

```
a & b       # Intersection: members which appear in both sets
a | b       # Union: all members from both sets
a - b       # Difference: members which are in a, but not in b
a ^ b       # Exclusive or (XOR): members in either a or b, but not in both
```

To combine your lists into one final set, you can use unions:

```
Link_a =     set(['a','b','c'])
Bookmark_a = set(['1','2','3'])
Link_b =     set(['b','c'])
Bookmark_b = set(['4','5'])
Link_c =     set(['a'])
Bookmark_c = set(['6'])

Answer_link_all = set(Link_a | Link_b | Link_c)
Answer_bookmark_all = set(Bookmark_a | Bookmark_b | Bookmark_c)
```

Things are a bit different if you are using Python 3. Mostly it's the same, except you can also declare sets using this literal notation.

```
setName = {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1}      # result: class 'set': {1, 2, 3}
```