# Adding together the contents of a second list whenever an item appears in a first list

Tags: python, list, addition

I have two lists: tags and weights (these line up together: weight[i] is for tag[i]). Tags can appear multiple times. So, what I'm trying to do is add together all of the weights for each tag, to get a total weight per tag.

The lists look like this

```
tags = ['alternative', 'indie', 'jam rock', 'indie', 'alternative', 'punk']
weights = [100, 20, 45, 50, 75, 50]
```

What I'm trying to get would be something like:

```
tags = ['alternative', 'indie', 'jam rock', 'punk']
weights =[175, 70, 45, 50]
```

I've tried using all sorts of loops, but I can't figure out how to get this properly. I've been using `.remove(i)`, which will get rid of the duplicate tags, but that's about all I've been able to do.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Please, make your question more clear by providing inputs and expected outputs and what you've tried so far !

Comment: Pattern: iterate through the `weight` list using a counter or `zip()`. Build a dict using the tag as the key and a list of weights as the value.

Comment: Alright, I've edited to clarify!

Comment: And here's a hint: you can use `defaultdict`

Comment: May this help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114954/detect-remove-duplicate-values-in-a-list#comment57950408_35114954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary (or a defaultdict if you want to simplify your code).

```
tags = ['alternative', 'indie', 'jam rock', 'indie', 'alternative', 'punk']
weights = [100, 20, 45, 50, 75, 50]
d = {}
for tag, weight in zip(tags, weights):
    if tag in d:
        d[tag] += weight
    else:
        d[tag] = weight

new_tags = [tag for tag in sorted(d)] #if you want it in alphabetical order
new_weights = [d[tag] for tag in new_tags]
print new_tags
print new_weights
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach you could make use of Python's `Counter` as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

tags = ['alternative', 'indie', 'jam rock', 'indie', 'alternative', 'punk']
weights = [100, 20, 45, 50, 75, 50]
totals = Counter()

for t, w in zip(tags, weights):
    totals[t] += w

print totals
```

This would display the following output:

```
Counter({'alternative': 175, 'indie': 70, 'punk': 50, 'jam rock': 45})
```

The `totals` can then be used as you would a normal dictionary, e.g. `print totals['indie']` would return `70`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a dictionary in this situation, as it is easy for parallel lists to get misaligned. Here is an example using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), like iron fist suggested in the comments.

```
from collections import defaultdict
tagDict = defaultdict(int)
tags = ['alternative', 'indie', 'jam rock', 'indie', 'alternative', 'punk']
weights = [100, 20, 45, 50, 75, 50]

for i in range(len(tags)):
    tagDict[tags[i]] += weights[i]

print tagDict
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `defaultdict` from `collections`:

```
>>> tags = ['alternative', 'indie', 'jam rock', 'indie', 'alternative', 'punk']
>>> weights = [100, 20, 45, 50, 75, 50]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> 
>>> for k,v in zip(tags, weights):
        d[k] += v

>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'jam rock': 45, 'punk': 50, 'alternative': 175, 'indie': 70})
>>> 
>>> d['alternative']
175
```